# How can I send emails with laravel from my development environment, and what do users receive?

Tags: laravel, email

I have got my application to send an email but the person does not receive it.
I know you send them because I am using mailtrap.io

Comment: Either setup an SMTP server or a service like mailgun

Comment: if it's for testing purpose, you can use mailtrap

Comment: I am using mailtrap but the user does not receive any confirmation email

Comment: Please share you code so far.